# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'., flutter

Tags: flutter, gradle, build.gradle

I don't know whats causing this error in flutter, I just tried to create a new project and I am getting this error, I have upgraded and also downgraded my flutter SDK still the same error keeps popping out when I do flutter run this is the full error :

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
* What went wrong:
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
   > Failed to transform artifact 'savedstate.aar (androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.0.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
      > org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Failed to create directory 'C:\Users\<myPCname>\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\0e6d0f8153e855bafef0a18ed5b156d5'
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
* Try:
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
BUILD FAILED in 16m 26s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                      1010.3s (!)
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You can use triple backticks to add code formatting. Like so: ``` code ```. This makes errors easier to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I simply solved it by changing:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'

    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

to:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'

    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

and my project worked, without any more problems

Answer (score -1):

```
        https://www.jitpack.io/com/github/agorabuilder/native-full-sdk/3.5.2/native-full-sdk-3.5.2.jar
```

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org